# Using str_replace to alter the_title()

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, str-replace

I have this code snippet :

```
$nieuwetitel = the_title();
echo str_replace('Bijenkorf', 'test', $nieuwetitel);
```

`the_title()` outputs the following: *Bijenkorf – Acne Studios Adriana €360*

Using the code mentioned above, I would like to change 'Bijenkorf' to 'test', however this does not seem to work.

In the end I would like to create a list of things to exclude from `the_title()` (Bijenkorf is one of them).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [the_title](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_title) filter for this.

Here is the code.

```
function wh_alterProductTitle($title, $id = NULL)
{
    //for only changing product title
    if ('product' == get_post_type($id))
    {
        //for single
        $title = str_replace('Bijenkorf', 'test', $title);
        //for multiple
        //$title = str_replace(['find1', 'find2'], 'test', $title);
    }
    return $title;
}

add_filter('the_title', 'wh_alterProductTitle', 10, 2);
```

Hope this helps!